# Generalization of class in generic function creates object code for base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
class A {
protected:
    int fooA;
    A() : fooA(0) {}
};

class B {};

template<typename T>
class C : public A {
public:
    using A::A;

    void fooF(T& element) {
        element.fooA = 1;
    }
};

class D : public C<B>, public B {
    using C::C;
};

int main() {

    D d1;
    D d2;

    d1.fooF(d2);

    return 0;
}
```

```
error: ‘const class B’ has no member named ‘fooA’ element.fooA = 1;
```

It seems like when `T` is particulariced into `B`, it transforms `d2` into its parent class (`B`), what can I do to avoid that? 
(I need to do it that way so i can't change the number of classes either its inheritances).
Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a bad design. Just curious why the number of classes or its inheritances cannot be changed?

Comment: It's an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want... but I suspect you want something as

```
template<typename T>
class C : public A {
public:
    using A::A;

    template <typename U>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<C<T>, U>::value>::type
       fooF (U element)
     { element.fooA = 1; }
};
```

I mean... a template `fooF()` that receive a `C<T>` derived type.

Or maybe a `B` derived type

```
    template <typename U>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B, U>::value>::type
       fooF (U element)
     { element.fooA = 1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like when T is particulariced into B, it transforms d2 into its parent class (B), what can I do to avoid that?

Don't take in a `T` in `fooF`.  Taking a `T` is what is slicing the object and just giving you the `B` part of it.  If you take in a `C<T>` instead then you will have access to the `A` part of the object.  Also, `fooF` is taking a `const` variable, so you can't modify that.  Changing it to a reference, so the change sticks to the object you passed would give you

```
void fooF(C<T>& element) {
    element.fooA = 1;
}
```

Comment: Mhhh yeah, the real problem it's a little more complicated, imagine that there is one more class E:

    `class E : public B, public C {};`

So I need fooF() work with E or D only, and exclusively when T is B.

Comment: @RoastMyCodeSpankyWanky Then just make it `void fooF(C<B>& element)`?